# Bind an inline dynamic css class name using VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using VueJs, is it possible to do something like this?

**Html:**

```
<div class="someStaticClass {{someDynamicClass}}">...</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = new Vue({
    data: {
        someDynamicClass: 'myClassName'
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.someDynamicClass = 'myOtherClassName';
    }
});
```

I know from [VueJs documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) that I can bind using a JS object, but, I'm hoping to write it more simply w/ an inline variable. Thanks!

Comment: you can do that just like one parentheses like this : class="{someDynamicClass}"

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih unfortunately that remains as `class="{someDynamicClass}"` and doesn't actually fill it w/ the value of the property. I tried w/ both `class=...` and `:class=...` and it did not render as intended.

Comment: hum, I'm sorry just try {this.someDynamicClass}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if that's what you mean?

```
<div class="someStaticClass" :class="{dynamicClassHere: ifConditionIsTrue}">...</div>
```

You could use a computed property to give you back the class name string based on some other logic then always return true in the if condition.

```
<div class="someStaticClass" :class="{computedProperty: true}">...</div>
```